# Perl readdir in order

Tags: perl, sorting, directory, readdir

Is there any way to guarantee an order from the list returned by `readdir`?

I have the code:

```
opendir(my $DIR, $src) or die "Error opening $src";

# Loop for each file in the directory
while (my $file = readdir($DIR))
{
        print "$file\n";
    }
```

But it returns in random order. Now I know there are plenty of solutions via a quick Google search, but I can't find the exact order I need.
Basically I want the folders to appear FIRST or LAST, and not in between the files.

For example, right now if I have the folder structure:

```
folder
folder
file1
file2
file3
```

I get the result:

```
file2
folder
folder
file1
file3
```

When really I want:

```
folder
folder
file1
file2
file3
```

Or:

```
file1
file2
file3
folder
folder
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: some kind of sort should be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort by putting folders first and then sorting by file/dir name,

```
# $src pointing to folder open with opendir
my @sorted_dir = 
  map $_->[0],
  sort {
    $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]
      ||
    $a->[0] cmp $b->[0]
  }
  map [ $_, -f "$src/$_" ],
  readdir($DIR);
```

While similar effect can be achieved with,

```
for my $file (sort { -f "$src/$a" <=> -f "$src/$b" } readdir($DIR)) {
  print "$file\n";
}
```

it's slower and inefficient as it more often goes to file system checking if directory entry is a plain file.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a more elegant solution though. I will fall back to this if all else fails :)

Comment: Updated with simpler but slower alternative.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nicer looking one. That was also the issue with the other solution provided by simbabque, it was missing `$src/` and that's why it wasn't working!

Comment: Also note that second one doesn't sort by entry names.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `sort` to do it, by looking at each entry of the list returned by `readdir`.

```
opendir(my $DIR, '.') or die "Error opening ";

foreach my $file (sort { -d $a <=> -d $b } readdir($DIR)) {
  print "$file\n";
}
```

This will give folders last.

Comment: Hi, when I do this I get `Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>)`.

Comment: Try `cmp` instead of `<=>`.

Comment: Now I get `Use of uninitialized value in string comparison (cmp)`. Removing the `-d` from both yields no errors (but obviously wrong output)..

Comment: Looks like there is empty stuff in the return values of `readdir`. `<=>` is correct, btw. `cmp` is alphanumeric, and `-d` only returns `0` and `1`, so no `cmp` needed.

Answer (score 5):

`foreach (sort readdir $dh) {}` works fine for me.

For example:

```
opendir (my $DIR, "$dir") || die "Error while opening $dir: $!\n";

foreach my $dirFileName(sort readdir $DIR)
{
      next if $dirFileName eq '.' or $dirFileName eq '..';
      print("fileName: $dirFileName ... \n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `part` from [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'part';

my $dir = shift || '.';

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Cannot open $dir";

my ($files, $dirs) = part { -d } sort readdir $dh;

print "$_\n" for @$files, @$dirs;
```

For another idea, you might look at [File::Next](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aNext).

Comment: It works, its easy to read, and you almost certainly have it already. But ... your choice.